# psql Use of a constant list of values as a table

Tags: postgresql

Using psql I want to use a list of constants as a table as with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   sportstable as S,
   ('soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball') as T
WHERE
   S.id = someFunction(T.????)
```

I have the constants  ('soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball') and I need to apply a function on them in this case called  someFunction.

Is it possible to do something like this in psql? I know that list  ('soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball')  is not a table so I could be making a big mistake on the use of the concept but I am still curious if there is something that work like this in psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you can use a `values()` clause:

```
select *
from sportstable s
  cross join ( 
     values ('soccer'), ('tennis'), ('baskedball')
  ) as t(sport)
where s.id = somefunction(t.sport);
```

But this might duplicate the rows from `sportstable` which you might not want.

I think you rather want:

```
select *
from sportstable s
where exists (select *
              from ( 
                 values ('soccer'), ('tennis'), ('baskedball')
              ) as t(sport)
              where s.id = somefunction(t.sport));
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I also found: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-values.html